# Pattern for exposing non generic and generic Class

Tags: c#, generics

I have implemented a common operation result for my methods and it look like this

```
public class OperResult
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public object Data { get; private set; }
    public bool Ok { get; private set; }
    public string IncidentNumber { get; set; }

    public static OperResult Success(Object data = null)
    {
        return new OperResult(data);
    }
}
```

And the same operation result using generics

```
public class OperResult<T>
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public T Data { get; private set; }
    public bool Ok { get; private set; }
    public string IncidentNumber { get; private set; }

    public static OperResult<T> Success(T data = null)
    {
        return new OperResult<T>(data);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to combine these two implementations and at the same time provide both Generic and non Generic version of this class?

---

Edit add more info about the type usage:

I want to easily create functions that return this type, for example i want to been able to create the following functions:

```
OperResult MakeAction()
OperResult<int> GetCount()
```

If I use inheritance `OperResult:OperResult<Object>` then `OperResult.Suceess()` will produce `OperResult<Object>` and the following will generate a compilation error:

```
OperResult MakeAction(){
  return OperResult.Suceess(); //Cannot convert OperResult<Object> to OperResult
}
```

[GitHub link to `OperResult`](https://github.com/melenaos/snippets/blob/master/OperResult)

Comment: What do you have in mind how that should look like? btw: seems the non-generic is in fact a `OperResult<object>`.

Comment: And the **drumroll**, why?

Comment: already mentioned in the comments `class OperResult: OperResult<object> { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the non generic appears to be a `OperResult<object>`.

Originally went down that route but it proved to not suit the desired use case.
Switched it around to having the generic derive from the non generic and provide a new Data property.

```
public class OperResult {

    protected OperResult(object data) {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public string ErrorCode { get; protected set; }
    public string Message { get; protected set; }
    public object Data { get; protected set; }
    public bool Ok { get; protected set; }
    public string IncidentNumber { get; protected set; }

    public static OperResult Success(object data = null) {
        return new OperResult(data ?? new object());
    }

    public static OperResult<T> Success<T>(T data) {
        return new OperResult<T>(data);
    }
}

public class OperResult<T> : OperResult {

    public OperResult(T data)
        : base(data) {
    }

    public new T Data { get; protected set; }
}
```

this allows the following syntax

```
int data = 10;
var result = OperResult.Success(data);
//result is OperResult<int>
```

Comment: The `OperResult.Success();` is `OperResult<Object>` not `OperResult`. This way you cannot create a function that returns `OperResult`

Comment: But given that `OperResult` is `OperResult<Object>` the result is valid. You could still create an overload.

Comment: `(OperResult)OperResult<object>` will produce a runtime error if this is what you suggesting.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis I had an idea and Working on a new angle now

Comment: @MenelaosVergis take a look at the new approach

Comment: I guess it's an decent implementation, you could move the Generic methods to the generic class to keep the generics together. Personally I will keep the two different implementations in my project, the inheritance doens't add that much value. Thank for your help on understanding the problem.